# nodejs - how to search within last some documents in mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**Nodejs**

```
dbo.collection("abc")
    .find({"name": "Felicity"})
    .sort({_id:-1})
    .limit()
    .exec(
        function(err, results){

            // my code

        }
    );
```

**Data in  Collection**

```
cansOne = [
   {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Khalichi",
        "gender": "F",
        "type":"Admin"
    },
    .
    .
    .

    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Thore",
        "gender": "M",
        "type":""
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "John Snow",
        "gender": "M",
        "type":"Admin"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Felicity",
        "gender": "F",
        "type":"User"
    }
]

cansTwo = [
   {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Khalichi",
        "gender": "F",
        "type":"Admin"
    },
    .
    .
    .

    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Thore",
        "gender": "M",
        "type":""
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "John Snow",
        "gender": "M",
        "type":"Admin"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Felicity",
        "gender": "F",
        "type":"User"
    }
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Batman",
        "gender": "M",a
        "type":""
    }
]
```

I have this type of data in collection. there are two type of cases:

1) `"type":""` at the end of collection, means it is last document of collection.

2) After `"type":""` document, there are some documents in collection.

I want to search one document, but if it is coming after last index of `"type":""` document then it will return that doc otherwise it will return null. in short I want to search this record in those amount of data which are comes after last `"type":""`

Can anyone help.

Thanks in advance.

For example I want to search `"name": "Felicity"`.

**Expected output**

```
caseOne = [
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5ace23558980..."),
        "name": "Felicity",
        "gender": "F",
        "type":"User"
    }
]

caseTwo = []
```

Comment: Hi Vipul; can I ask what _order_ of the collection you're thinking of? Because if you're relying on whether a particular record is after another record, that depends on what order you're using to list the documents.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this with Mongo query alone, or with your application code? Mongo query alone cannot do this AFAIK, you cannot find a document depends on its relative position to other documents. You need to use application code along with Mongo query, something like:

```
dbo.collection("abc").find({
    $or: [{
        name: "Felicity"
    }, {
        type: ""
    }]
})
.sort({
    _id: -1
})
.limit()
.exec(
    function(err, results) {
        // results here contains documents having name: Falicity or type: ""
        // do your check here

    }
);
```

Comment: not like this,  Felicity comes tow times but I want it if it comes after last type = "" so I cant use or condition.

Comment: if you write mongo query only it'll help lot. other things I'll menage. thanks for replay sir.

Comment: As I said this can't be done by Mongo query alone. Using the code above, you need to write more code processing the `results` to get what you need